# how do i insert many values in a column in single query?

Tags: mysql

i have a mysql column called roles, i would like to insert many values at once instead of one value per query.

for example instead of making four queries to insert four values

```
INSERT INTO roles(roleName) VALUES('Admnistrator');
INSERT INTO roles(roleName) VALUES('SuperUser');
INSERT INTO roles(roleName) VALUES('Staff');
INSERT INTO roles(roleName) VALUES('Customers');
```

i would like it to make one single query. is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
INSERT INTO 
         roles(roleName) 
  VALUES ('Admnistrator'), 
         ('SuperUser'), 
         ('Staff'), 
         ('Customers');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `roles` (`roleName`) 
     VALUES ('Admnistrator'),
     VALUES ('SuperUser'),
     VALUES ('Staff'),
     VALUES ('Customers');
```

Just comma separate them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
You can do:

```
INSERT INTO roles(roleName) VALUES('Admnistrator'),
('SuperUser'),
('Staff'),
('Customers');
```

Answer (score 0):

Inserting the multiple row into a mysql database using a single query. You just need to add the other values in the  **values**  section with comma separated.

```
Insert INTO Table_name (coulmn1 , column2, column3) 
VALUES (row1value,row1value,row1value),
       (row2value,row2value,row2value),
       (row3value,row3value,row3value);
```